# outputing value of cookies to prompt box

Tags: javascript, cookies

this code doesnt properly display the cookie value, it has the name of the cookie before for example email=.... I just want the value to appear?
the cookies are saving fine as i can view them in google chrome settings

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function setUserCookie() {
var els = document.forms.frm1.elements;
var cookiesToSet = ['first_name','email','fav'];
for (var i=cookiesToSet.length;i--;){
  var name = cookiesToSet[i];
  setCookie(name, els[name].value, 365);
  prompt(document.cookie);
}

}

    <form id="frm1">
            <input name="first_name" required="true" type="text" id="first_name"> 
            <input name="email" required="true" type="text" id="email">

            <h4>Favourite Destination</h4><select required="" id="fav">
                <option>
                    Copenhagen
                </option>

                <option>
                    Helsinki
                </option>

                <option>
                    Oslo
                </option>

                <option>
                    Stockholm
                </option>
            </select> <input id="SideBarSubmit" type="submit" value=
            "Subscribe"  onclick="setUserCookie();" >
        </form>
```

Comment: if anyone could help that would be great, i am storing the values of a form to cookies

Comment: Where is `setCookie` defined?

Answer (score 0):

As your code is shown, when you store the value to your cookie, you used `els[name]`  instead of `els[name].value`. You can either change your value store to `els[name].value`:

```
els[name].value = "abcd";
```

or retrieve value on `els[name]`:

```
function setUserCookie() {
    var els = document.forms.frm1.elements;
    var cookiesToSet = ['first_name','email','fav'];
    for (var i=cookiesToSet.length;i--;){
        var name = cookiesToSet[i];
        setCookie(name, els[name], 365);
        prompt(document.cookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work :( the prompt box appears 3 times and still says email=....; first_name=....;

Comment: @JonnyD your javascript did not have a close tag?